# Cannot find module pip installed from gitlab private registry

Tags: python, gitlab

I created a python library according to [this example](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/packages/pypi_repository/) in a private gitlab package registry.
I pip install the library and it works. When I pip freeze I can see my library.
But when I try to import it in python script I got a `ModuleNotFoundError`. 
 Did someone has already had this problem ?

Comment: Please include the code you have, the install command output, and the full error message/traceback. Also does installing your package locally work? (like `pip install .` then change directories out of the project, can you import it?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In fact it was a folder architecture problem.

I had that

`mypackage/`
-- `setup.py`
-- `__init__.py`

I tansformed it in 
`mypackage/`
-- `setup.py`
-- `mypackage/`
---- `__init__.py`


And it finally works

Comment: Thank you so much. I wonder why isn't document clear